# Как в строке оставить символ №

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция:

```
strval(preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\d\s_\-\.\%\s]/ui', '', $val)
```

Она удаляет символ **`№`** из строки. 
Как мне оставить этот символ?

Comment: Ну так добавь символ внутрь выражения, чтобы не удалял.....

Answer (score -2):

```php
strval(preg_replace('/[^№\p{L}\p{Nd}\d\s_\-\.\%\s]/ui', '', $val)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0fGdZS/1
В класс символов добавлен `№`.

Другой вопрос, зачем тут `strval`.